# Sorting a std::vector of struct's in ascending order

Tags: c++, sorting

Suppose that we have a `struct` and a `std::vector`, defined as:

```
struct example { 
   int x;       
   int height;
   std::string type; 
};

std::vector<example> objects;
```

First of all, we sort `objects` in ascending order, based on values of `x`, which can be implemented pretty easy:

```
std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](const example &a, const example &b) {
    return a.x < b.x;
});
```

But if values of `x` are the same, There are three conditions need to be handled based on other properties. Consider the following as our objects:

```
x:0,height:3,type:"start"
x:7,height:11,type:"start"
x:5,height:8,type:"end"
x:1,height:4,type:"start"
x:3,height:6,type:"start"
x:4,height:7,type:"start"
x:1,height:5,type:"start"
x:5,height:9,type:"end"
x:7,height:12,type:"end"
x:6,height:10,type:"start"
```

After insertion, I sort them based on values of `x` using the code written above, and the result would look like this:

```
x:0,height:3,type:"start"
x:1,height:4,type:"start"
x:1,height:5,type:"start"
x:3,height:6,type:"start"
x:4,height:7,type:"start"
x:5,height:8,type:"end"
x:5,height:9,type:"end"
x:6,height:10,type:"start"
x:7,height:11,type:"end"
x:7,height:12,type:"start"
```

Now there are modifications I need to do to the above vector (which is sorted based on values of `x`, only.

*Condition 1*: If values of `x` and `type` are the same, and the `type` equals to *start*, the object with the larger `height` must come before.

*Condition 2*: If values of `x` and `type` are the same, and the `type` equals to *end*, the object with the smaller `height` must come before.

*Condition 3*: If values of `x` are the same and the values of `type` are not, the object with *start* `type` must come before.

So, the final sorted vector should look like this:

```
x:0,height:3,type:"start"
x:1,height:5,type:"start"
x:1,height:4,type:"start"
x:3,height:6,type:"start"
x:4,height:7,type:"start"
x:5,height:8,type:"end"
x:5,height:9,type:"end"
x:6,height:10,type:"start"
x:7,height:12,type:"start"
x:7,height:11,type:"end"
```

How these conditions can be implemented?

Comment: You are already using a lambda as last argument to `std::sort`. You can specify further ordering requirements in there (it must return `true` if `a` should come before `b` and `false` otherwise). Do you have a specific problem with that?

Comment: Simply implement your logic in the lambda closure. There are no special tricks to it.

Comment: im not sure about syntax if someone has time and give an example it would be great for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing just `return a.x < b.x;`, insert all your conditions. What is important to notice is that the expression `a.x < b.x` evaluates to a `boolean` value: true or false. If the expression is true, the first element(in this case a), will come first in the sorted array.

You could create your conditions as such:

```
if(a.x == b.x) {
    if(a.type.compare(b.type) == 0){ //the types are equal
        //condition one
        if(a.type.compare("start") == 0) {
            return a.height > b.height;
        }
        //condition two
        if(a.type.compare("end") == 0) {
            return a.height < b.height;
        }
    }
    else { //types are not equal, condition three
        if(a.type.compare("start") == 0) //the type of a is start
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
else {
    return a.x < b.x;
}
```

It would be a good idea to put this code in a compare function:

```
bool compare(const exampleStruct& a, const exampleStruct& b)
{
    //the code written above
}
```

And call the std::sort as:

```
std::sort(objectVector.begin(), objectVector.end(), compare);
```

Comment: why do you use `string::compare`??

Comment: You can also use ==. I come from a java background, and there you have to use the compare function, the == operator does not work. I didn't know that the == operator is overloaded for strings in c++.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward. Just follow the logic in your comparator:

```
std::sort(objectVector.begin(), objectVector.end(), [](exampleStruct a, exampleStruct b) {
    if (a.x != b.x)
        return a.x < b.x;

    // a.x == b.x

    if (a.type == b.type)
    {
        if (a.type == "start")
            return a.height > b.height;
        if (a.type == "end")
            return a.height < b.height;

        throw std::invalid_argument("invalid type");
    }

    // a.x == b.x && a.type != b.type

    if (a.type == "start")
        return true;
    if (b.type == "start")
        return false;

    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid type");
});
```